# How to create new file extension?

Tags: file-format, file-type

I need to create custom file extension like `myfile.foo`

for scripting files how can i configure this ?

Comment: what exactly do you want to happen? Are you trying to associate files with a program?

Comment: actually i'm trying to build small scripting language for education purposes and i'm using python as an interpreter but i have no idea how to create an extension for this language files all i got is plain text document (text/plain)

Comment: On Linux, you can call any script file like you want. test.banana will run from the python interpreter if either you run `python test.banana` (or more likely `python3 test.banana`, or make the file executable and add the shebang. The extension plays no role whatsoever. Different on windows though.